# Resample Daily OHLCV to Weekly OHLCV

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to resample/convert Daily (ohlcv) to Weekly (ohlcv).  Is it possible to do this with pandas?

The sample data is as follows (1 week daily data) in dictionary format:

```
   {'High': {<Timestamp: 2007-03-02 00:00:00>: 1384.5,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-05 00:00:00>: 1373.0,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-06 00:00:00>: 1378.75,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-07 00:00:00>: 1381.75,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-08 00:00:00>: 1388.75},
 'Last': {<Timestamp: 2007-03-02 00:00:00>: 1365.0,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-05 00:00:00>: 1351.5,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-06 00:00:00>: 1374.5,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-07 00:00:00>: 1372.0,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-08 00:00:00>: 1384.5},
 'Low': {<Timestamp: 2007-03-02 00:00:00>: 1364.25,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-05 00:00:00>: 1350.5,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-06 00:00:00>: 1362.0,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-07 00:00:00>: 1370.75,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-08 00:00:00>: 1369.25},
 'Open': {<Timestamp: 2007-03-02 00:00:00>: 1378.5,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-05 00:00:00>: 1356.75,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-06 00:00:00>: 1365.25,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-07 00:00:00>: 1374.0,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-08 00:00:00>: 1370.0},
 'Volume': {<Timestamp: 2007-03-02 00:00:00>: 1706906,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-05 00:00:00>: 1984041,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-06 00:00:00>: 1397911,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-07 00:00:00>: 1255484,
  <Timestamp: 2007-03-08 00:00:00>: 798237}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you have your data in a DataFrame you can do this:

```
 ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    'Volume':'sum'
    }

DataFrame.resample('W-Fri', how=ohlc_dict)
```

This will give you ohlc data for the week ending on a Friday.

Comment: @aozkan the keys are the names of the columns, and the values are the named functions for computing the value

Comment: @aozkan maybe this will make the syntax more clear: to form a weekly OHLC bar from daily data you need to take the lowest low of all the daily bars within that week, this is why "low" is "min". Then you take the highest high of all the daily bars, this is why "high" is "max'. Then you take the first open of the daily bars (since this is the open of the week) which is why "open" is "first" and finally you take the close of the last daily bar (which is the close of the week) which is why "close" is "last". The volume you simply sum up over the week. Still magic but hope it helps a bit :)

Comment: 2020 update, use: DataFrame.resample('W-Fri').apply(ohlc_dict)

Answer (score 3):

After pandas version `0.18.0`, the `how` parameter became deprecated in function `resample`, and thus the proposed solution became:

```
ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    'Volume':'sum'
    }

df = df.resample('W').agg(ohlc_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Example adapted from the official documentation:

```
# Weekly means
In [1305]: ts.resample('W', how='mean')
Out[1305]: 
2011-01-01   -0.319569
2011-01-02   -0.337703
2011-01-03    0.117258
Freq: W
```

You could offset the dates to a specific day of the week with, for example `'W-SUN'` or `'W-MON'`.

[Link to documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.Series.resample)

Comment: My goal is to convert the daily ohlcv to weekly ohlcv. For example the weekly High Column would take the highest high from the daily data for that particular week.  The Volume would take the total sum for all days during that particular week.